# How to set up demo client for graph-ql integration in flutter

Tags: flutter, graphql

I don't know much about graph-ql and need a demo setup that could run.
I am stuck and don't know how to setup client,
Can anybody could explain me how to setup client in this given code:-

https://github.com/zino-app/graphql-flutter/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart

```
 Client(
        endPoint: 'https://api.github.com/graphql',
        cache: InMemoryCache(),
        apiToken: '<YOUR_GITHUB_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN>',
      ),
```

also what is ReadRepositories in

```
String readRepositories = """
  query ReadRepositories {
    viewer {
      repositories(last: 50) {
        nodes {
          id
          name
          viewerHasStarred
        }
      }
    }
  }
"""
    .replaceAll('\n', ' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static HttpLink httpLink = HttpLink(
  uri: 'https://api.github.com/graphql',
);

final AuthLink authLink = AuthLink(
  getToken: () async => 'Bearer <YOUR_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN>',
);

final Link link = authLink.concat(httpLink as Link);

ValueNotifier<GraphQLClient> client = ValueNotifier(
  GraphQLClient(
    cache: InMemoryCache(),
    link: link,
  ),
);
```

For Call query user Query method for GraphQlProvider.

```
Query(
  options: QueryOptions(document: readRepositories, pollInterval: 1),
  builder: (QueryResult result, {VoidCallback refetch}) {
    if (result.loading) {
      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    }
    if (result.errors != null) {
      return Text(result.errors.toString());
    }
    if (result.data == null) {
      return Center(child: Text("No Data Found !"));
    }
    // After getting response, return your result 
      return YourWidget();
    },
);
```

Comment: yeaahh this is good approaching, for return YourWidget();.. after get result back... but could you explain, how to move to another page instead of YourWidget().. because im stuck in case of moving to another page.. :(